# How to add JVM parameters in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

IN one of AWS glue job we have a long running transaction which fails with below error
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io exception: Connection reset

This is a common issue from Oracle and the solution provided by them is to use -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom

Where can we add this in AWS glue. In the doc it is mentioned not to use -conf variable as job parameter as it is internally used by AWS glue

Please let us know if there are any solutions for this

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter --java-options and in the value add the JVM -D parameters